# How to end old Activity when Search starts new Activity

Tags: android, search, listactivity, searchable

I have an application that presents a sort of catalog of items in a `ListView`.  The list is rather long, so I've implemented the `Search` capability like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".ItemsOverview"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to ItemsSearch -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".ItemsSearch" />
    </activity>
...
...
    <activity android:name=".ItemsSearch">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

`ItemsSearch` then presents the same `ListView`, but containing only items that match the Search criteria.

There are two fundamental problems with this:

1. `ItemsSearch` is an almost duplicate of `ItemsOverview` (but with some enhancements for the search capability);
2. `ItemsSearch` overlays `ItemsOverview` such that if three or four searches are done, it takes four or five presses of the Back button to get out.  Not quite the desired effect.  :)

I would like to, in some fashion, end the original Activity when the second Activity starts and, ideally, combine the two Classes (Overview and Search) into one. Is there a way for my Activity to detect that it's already running in another process, and to kill that other process at inception?

Once I understand this, I can probably figure out how to combine the two.  What do others do when they need to utilize a filtered list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, you would you like to clear the Activity Back Stack. Use the activity flags when you call your search Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Search.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

[This is the developer page about the activity back stack.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

To end old Activity when Search starts new Activity give finish() in odler activity and call new activity.
`Intent intent = new (Intent(MainActivity.this,GPSActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_GPS);

finish();`

In this we can start new Activity GPSActivity and finishes MainActivity.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  But if the user presses Search by mistake, then I <finish> my app... back button will not undo all that.  User should not suffer for a miskey, right?